# i am trying to add http:// to a serious of files. I keep getting this error sed: -e expression #1, char 15: unknown option to `s' when using sed

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, sed

The command worked for my boss yesterday. The only difference is he is on a mac. Originally I thought it was a copy/past issue, but I still get the error when I type it by hand.

The command I am using is :

```
sed -i -e 's/^/http:\/\//'filename.txt
```

This is all being done on a Ec2 instance. And I am using vs code to connect.

Comment: On a Mac, use `sed -i '' 's~^~http://~' filename.txt`

Comment: It's not just that that you forgot a space before `filename.txt`?  `sed -i -e 's/^/http:\/\//' filename.txt` - Since you use `/` in the expression, perhaps using `,` as a delimiter makes it easier: `sed -i -e 's,^,http://,' filename.txt` or just `sed -i 's,^,http://,' filename.txt`

Comment: Voting to close this as a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
sed -i'.bak' -e 's/^/http:\/\//' filename.txt
```